# Count data entries per day per person

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

My employees enter samples into our database. This is done by a forum. I have access to Google sheet that houses all the info they provide. They enter multiple entries a day. I am trying to find who is the top performer, that has entered the most entries in one day.

How do I get it to search my data to tell me the person's name and how many samples they are entered in per day?

Ex.

```
Tim= 15 entries on Sept 10 

John= 5 entries on Sept 10

Brian= 2 entries on sept 10 

Tim= 5 entries on sept 9

John= 20 entries sept 9

Brian= 1 entrie on sept 9
```

I want it to look through the list and pick up that Johns entries on the 9th are the highest and it outputs me johns name and 20 entries. Until a day comes that someone enters more than 20 entries it will hold john as being my top performer

Comment: https://docs.google.com/a/lafargeholcim.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vS3MdrUnxFuicoRgfqbrhXn-GC6VPQ8MtfcHqi1lxT7t8-KAQAHJaDJAM_JjPxQA0eN1WyxQ84pkmUa/pubhtml - Here is a link to the example. I believe Column B and E are what I want to work with. I need it to look at the date. and tell me who has the most entries in one day

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: hmmm Doesn't seem like my admins will let me share documents

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14O5XNgK2oypNphro0TxMDUsyGNIVnZYUHmo0p_UG6Kk/edit?usp=sharing   try this link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `QUERY` like:

```
=QUERY(A:C, "order by C desc limit 1", 0)
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=QUERY(B2:E, "select B,count(B) where B is not null group by B label count(B)''", 0)
```

[image: 0]

```
=QUERY(B2:E, "select B,count(B) where B is not null group by B pivot E", 0)
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
 {B2:B&"♦"&TEXT(E2:E, "m/d/yyyy")}, 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  order by count(Col1) desc 
  label count(Col1)''", 0))&"♦",,999^99)), "♦"), 
 "limit 1 
  offset 1", 0))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Not sure that will work for me. Need to count how many times that name shows up under a certain date. I try to reload my example

Comment: sure: `=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
 {B2:B&"♦"&TEXT(E2:E, "m/d/yyyy")}, 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  order by count(Col1) desc 
  label count(Col1)''", 0))&"♦",,999^99)), "♦"), 
 "limit 3 
  offset 1", 0))`